# How can I move to subsequent web pages after POST (ing) a html form in R?

Tags: html, r, post, rcurl, httr

A happy and a prosperous New Year, 2016 to everyone.

Here, I am using NCDC website to download weather data from say 01-Jan-2015 to 31-Mar-2015 for a state in the US say Connecticut. The link is mentioned below in the script. From filling details on this webpage to page in which you click on submit after entering your email id, there are intermediate pages that require some inputs  before continuing on to a next page. My goal is to write a R script that automatically triggers download (submit order) for different states for different time periods after providing required inputs.

For purpose of ease, I am putting steps that one need to follow to download data for Connecticut. These steps are (please go through 2 snapshots attached):

1. Step-1 : Here, you select a dataset, State name, and time period-
   4 values that would go in the form on landing page are Daily Summaries, 2015-01-01 to 2015-03-31, States, and Connecticut.

   ```
   library(httr)
   url <- "http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/search?datasetid=GHCND"

   fd <- list(
              submit = "Search",
              searchStartDate  = "2015-01-01",
              searchEndDate = "2015-03-31",
              resultType   = "States",
              searchString = "Connecticut"
            )
   resp<-POST(url, body=fd, encode="form")
   ```
2. Step-2 : [Here, you would need to click first on ADD TO CART and then on View All Items under Cart. This would be possible, if we operate on resp from above step. I am not able to figure out a way to do this operation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW0hi.jpg)
3. Step-3 : Here, you need to select 2nd option under "Select the Output Format" before clicking on CONTINUE.
4. Step-4 : [Here, you have to select many options as highlighted in the image before clicking on CONTINUE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlzUg.png)
5. Step-5: Finally, you enter the email id and click on "SUBMIT ORDER".

If you need any other input from my end, do let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't yet gotten past the "review" screen, due to technical difficulties, according to the site.  The farthest along in the process that I could find the request parameters in the request body is at `http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/cart`, which was sent form data: `outputType.product.id: NEXRAD2_UNTAR
dataStartTime: 00:00
dataStartDate: 2015-01-01
dataSet: NEXRAD2
dataEndTime: 23:59
dataEndDate: 2015-03-31

`

Comment: It seems like you are just trying to download specific data.  Why not use [rnoaa](https://ropensci.org/blog/2014/03/13/rnoaa/)?  You can download NCDC data from that.

Comment: Thank you Lori for trying things at your end. I really appreciate.

Comment: Hi Amstell, thank you for replying and pointing me to rnoaa website. Yes I am trying to download specific data. The purpose of posting this question was also to learn how to use R script to navigate through such a set of pages automatically. I am facing a couple of issues while accessing data from rnoaa, and I just posted these issues on the link for rnoaa mentioned by you. Can you please look into this post and share your inputs?

Comment: Hi Lori. For good reason, I could not work on this problem. I have tried again, but I am not able to reach to even to next page. The strange thing is while through "Inspect", I am able to locate elements of cart and search results on 2nd webpage http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/results, "resp" variable in above script does not have these elements. For ex, there is an id="searchResults" that you can see when you "Inspect" but when you search for this element in content(resp), you do not find it.

Comment: Hence, can you please share steps that you followed to reach to http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/cart page so that I have a better understanding of technical difficulties that you faced? Since I am still new to these things, your steps would be helpful. Thank you again.